# Finding the most left digit in a number with Java

Tags: java, random, digit

I have to find the most left digit in a randomly generated number (for example: 46891 -> 4). No matter what the number is I keep getting zero. Here's one of the codes I try:

```
int num1 = (int)((Math.random()*100000)+1);

while((Math.floor(num1/10))>0)
    {
        num1 = (int)Math.floor(num1/10);
    }

    System.out.println("Left digit: " + num1);
```

I tried to use `Integer.parseInt`, but I got this mistake, obviously: The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (int).

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about this :

```
final Random r=new Random();
final int t=r.nextInt(100000)+1;
// naive way:
final String s=Integer.toString(t);
System.out.println("left digit is:"+s.charAt(0));
// "math" way:
int temp=t;
while(temp>=10)
  temp/=10;
System.out.println("left digit is:"+temp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborated answer! Everything works now!

Comment: But, Can math way be made better ? It essentially takes n! time. n - > total number of digits in it

Comment: @BalajiBoggaramRamanarayan Since "int" doesn't has a very finite and small number of digits (max value is 2,147,483,647, so max number of digits is 10), both solutions take O(1). If you use BigDecimal or BigInteger, these solutions will be much worse, and you might need to think of a different solution

Answer (score 3):

Integer division removes the fractional part, so all you need is a simple loop:

```
int num = (int)((Math.random()*100000)+1);
for ( ; num >= 10 ; num /= 10);
System.out.println(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there! The problem is, the `num1` will be a number, not a character, although they are basically the same thing. Convert it to a string using `.toString()` or use `System.out.format` with the `%i` format string.

EDIT: nevermind, I was wrong. You are doing the loop while `num1` is greater than 0, the problem being that this loop exits when `num1` is 0. In this case, you need to break one before, so I'd just change the test to `>=10`. In this case, you ensure you have a single digit, which given the nature of the question, must be greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `Math.floor` as integer division rounds down automatically.

And you want to check for `num1 > 9` in your loop, to only divide if number is at least 10.

**EDIT**: I tested your code and it works for me too, without modifications...

Comment: Yup, I answered to that a bit earlier here, it was my stupid mistake... Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I am using code based on yours

```
int num1 = (int)((Math.random()*100000)+1);
System.out.println("Randomed number: " + num1);
while((num1/10)>0)
        num1 = num1/10;
System.out.println("Left digit: " + num1);
```

and it works fine for me

Comment: It was my bad - before the loop I had some other code that changed the value of num1 to 0 and I didn't pay attention to it, that's what got me stuck. Stupid, I know... :-/ Well, it least it made me learn something new today, not to mention the lesson I learned to triple check every code I write. :)

Comment: @downvoter If you found something wrong with this answer can you tell what is it? I would like to improve/correct it.